# Display data in combobox (already loaded)

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am new in VB 2015. My problem is: MySQL table structure is as follows

1. `groupcode`
2. `groupname`
3. `AliasName`
4. `parentGroupCode` (this actually save the `groupcode` value)

I am showing Group Code & Group name as `valuemember` & `displaymember` in my combobox. Now I want to edit a record.

How to display the respective group name in the combobox? Please help me.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking for. Are you asking how to select a particular record in the `ComboBox` using code or are you saying that when you edit a record the text in the `ComboBox` for that row doesn't change?

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry for not making my question clear. However, I am asking for how to select a particular record in the ComboBox using code.

Comment: The you would set the `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` to the appropriate `GroupCode` value.